# What's wrong with this statement in Perl?

Tags: perl, unix

```
print "$_", join(',',sort keys %$h),"\n";
```

It's giving me an error below:

```
Use of uninitialized value in string at missing_months.pl line 36.
1,10,11,12
```

this print statement is present in a for loop  as below:

```
foreach my $num ( sort keys %hash )
{
        my $h = $hash{$num};
        print "$_", join(',',sort keys %$h),"\n";
}
```

Answer (score 14):

No need for the `"$_"`. That line should be:

```
print join (',' , sort {$a <=> $b} keys %$h),"\n";
```

While the `$_` is treated as the default iterator in `for` and `foreach` loops (see [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)), you've already assigned the iterator variable as `$num`.

Here is how to use the `$_` correctly in a single line:

```
print join(',', sort { $a <=> $b } keys %{$hash{$_}}),"\n" foreach keys %hash;
```

#### On a Side Note...

`sort` uses string comparison by default, meaning that `'10'` is deemed to come before `'2'`. It seems that you're dealing with months (perhaps?), which is why I've used the numerical comparison block `{ $a <=> $b }`.

Comment: there is a mistake here in your answer.You are right in saying that $_ is creating the problem.But i need the $num over here .So wht is did is istead of `print "$_", join(',',sort keys %$h),"\n";` i used `print "$num", join(',',sort keys %$h),"\n";`.this worked.